# Запуск нескольких exe файлов с помощью python

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

пытаюсь запустить несколько exe файлом один за одним используя subprocess.call
в результате вылетает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот весь код:

```
from tkinter import *
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip
import subprocess
# pyautogui.hotkey("win")

win = Tk()
win.title("win")
win.geometry("665x280")
win["bg"] = "gray6"



def ForNotebook ():
    subprocess.call('bin/Yandex.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/uTorrent.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/MicrosoftOffice.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/DriverBooster.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/UninstallTool.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/NotePad++.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/Picasa.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/MiniBin.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/EarTrumpet.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/Everything.exe')
    subprocess.call('bin/Lightshot.exe')


def ForPC ():
    print ("djfh")


def Install():
    if (Chrome.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Chrome.exe')
    if (Yandex.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Yandex.exe')
    if (FireFox.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/FireFox.exe')
    if (Opera.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Opera.exe')
    if (OperaGX.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/OperaGX.exe')
    if (Edge.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Edge.exe')
    if (Vivaldi.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Vivaldi.exe')
    if (uTorrent.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/uTorrent.exe')
    if (qBitTorrent.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/qBitTorrent.exe')
    if (Transmission.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Transmission.exe')
    if (MicrosoftOffice.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/MicrosoftOffice.exe')
    if (LibreOffice.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/LibreOffice.exe')
    if (CCleaner.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/CCleaner.exe')
    if (FastComputer.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/FastComputer.exe')
    if (IObitUninstaller.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/IObitUninstaller.exe')
    if (MiniTool.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/MiniTool.exe')
    if (RegOrganizer.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/RegOrganizer.exe')
    if (RevoUninstallerPro.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/RevoUninstallerPro.exe')
    if (UninstallTool.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/UninstallTool.exe')
    if (Atom.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Atom.exe')
    if (BlackNotePad.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/BlackNotePad.exe')
    if (Gvim.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Gvim.exe')
    if (NotePad.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/NotePad++.exe')
    if (SublimeText.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/SublimeText.exe')
    if (Thonny.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Thonny.exe')
    if (VSCode.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/VSCode.exe')
    if (Zip.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/7z.exe')
    if (CDbxp.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/CDbxp.exe')
    if (Everything.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Everything.exe')
    if (LockHunter.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/LockHunter.exe')
    if (Unlocker.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Unlocker.exe')
    if (Windirstat.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Windirstat.exe')
    if (winRAR.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/winRAR.exe')
    if (AIDA64.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/AIDA64.exe')
    if (AnvirTM.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/AnvirTM.exe')
    if (CoreTemp.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/CoreTemp.exe')
    if (CpuZ.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/CpuZ.exe')
    if (GpuZ.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/GpuZ.exe')
    if (HDTunePro.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/HDTunePro.exe')
    if (InfoCD.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/InfoCD.exe')
    if (MarkCD.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/MarkCD.exe')
    if (MSIAfterburner.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/MSIAfterburner.exe')
    if (AIMP.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/AIMP.exe')
    if (CyberLink.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/CyberLink.exe')
    if (Gimp.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Gimp.exe')
    if (KMPlayer.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/KMPlayer.exe')
    if (Lightshot.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Lightshot.exe')
    if (Picasa.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Picasa.exe')
    if (VLC.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/VLC.exe')
    if (Xrecode.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/Xrecode.exe')
    if (DriverBooster.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/DriverBooster.exe')
    if (DriverHub.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/DriverHub.exe')
    if (EarTrumpet.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/EarTrumpet.exe')
    if (MiniBin.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/MiniBin.exe')
    if (TimeER.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/TimeER.exe')
    if (VNCServer.get()):
        subprocess.call('bin/VNCServer.exe')





Chrome = IntVar(value=0)
ChromeC = Checkbutton(win,
                     text='Chrome', 
                     variable=Chrome, 
                     bg="gray6", 
                     fg="green3",  
                     activebackground="gray6", 
                     activeforeground="green3", 
                     selectcolor="gray6", 
                     )\
                     .place(x=10, y=1) 

Yandex = IntVar(value=0)
YandexC = Checkbutton(win,
                     text='Yandex', 
                     variable=Yandex, 
                     bg="gray6", 
                     fg="green3",  
                     activebackground="gray6", 
                     activeforeground="green3", 
                     selectcolor="gray6",
                     )\
                     .place(x=10, y=20)

FireFox = IntVar(value=0)
FireFoxC = Checkbutton(win,
                      text='FireFox',
                      variable=FireFox,
                      bg="gray6",
                      fg="green3",
                      activebackground="gray6",
                      activeforeground="green3",
                      selectcolor="gray6",
                      )\
                      .place(x=10, y=39)

Opera = IntVar(value=0)
OperaC = Checkbutton(win,
                     text='Opera',
                     variable=Opera,
                     bg="gray6",
                     fg="green3", 
                     activebackground="gray6",
                     activeforeground="green3",
                     selectcolor="gray6",
                     )\
                     .place(x=10, y=58)

OperaGX = IntVar(value=0)
OperaGXC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='OperaGX',
                  variable=OperaGX,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="green3", 
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=10, y=77)

Edge = IntVar(value=0)
EdgeC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Edge',
                    variable=Edge,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="green3",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=10, y=96)

Vivaldi = IntVar(value=0)
VivaldiC = Checkbutton(win,
                          text='Vivaldi',
                          variable=Vivaldi,
                          bg="gray6",
                          fg="green3", 
                          activebackground="gray6",
                          activeforeground="green3",
                          selectcolor="gray6",
                          )\
                          .place(x=10, y=115)

uTorrent = IntVar(value=0)
uTorrentC = Checkbutton(win,
                       text='uTorrent',
                       variable=uTorrent,
                       bg="gray6",
                       fg="green3",
                       activebackground="gray6",
                       activeforeground="green3",
                       selectcolor="gray6",
                       )\
                       .place(x=10, y=134)

qBitTorrent = IntVar(value=0)
qBitTorrentC = Checkbutton(win,
                          text='qBitTorrent',
                          variable=qBitTorrent,
                          bg="gray6",
                          fg="green3",
                          activebackground="gray6",
                          activeforeground="green3",
                          selectcolor="gray6",
                          )\
                          .place(x=10, y=153)

Transmission = IntVar(value=0)
TransmissionC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='Transmission',
                  variable=Transmission,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="green3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=10, y=172)

MicrosoftOffice = IntVar(value=0)
MicrosoftOfficeC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='MicrosoftOffice',
                  variable=MicrosoftOffice,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="green3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=10, y=191)

LibreOffice = IntVar(value=0)
LibreOfficeC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='LibreOffice',
                  variable=LibreOffice,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="green3", 
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=10, y=210)

CCleaner = IntVar(value=0)
CCleanerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='CCleaner',
                  variable=CCleaner,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="green3", 
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=10, y=229)

FastComputer = IntVar(value=0)
FastComputerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='FastComputer',
                  variable=FastComputer,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=1)

IObitUninstaller = IntVar(value=0)
IObitUninstallerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='IObitUninstaller',
                  variable=IObitUninstaller,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=20)

MiniTool = IntVar(value=0)
MiniToolC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='MiniTool',
                  variable=MiniTool,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=39)

RegOrganizer = IntVar(value=0)
RegOrganizerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='RegOrganizer',
                  variable=RegOrganizer,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=58)

RevoUninstallerPro = IntVar(value=0)
RevoUninstallerProC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='RevoUninstallerPro',
                  variable=RevoUninstallerPro,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=77)

UninstallTool = IntVar(value=0)
UninstallToolC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='UninstallTool',
                  variable=UninstallTool,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=96)

Atom = IntVar(value=0)
AtomC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Atom',
                    variable=Atom,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="cyan2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=150, y=115)

BlackNotePad = IntVar(value=0)
BlackNotePadC = Checkbutton(win,
                            text='BlackNotePad',
                            variable=BlackNotePad,
                            bg="gray6",
                            fg="cyan2",
                            activebackground="gray6",
                            activeforeground="green3",
                            selectcolor="gray6",
                            )\
                            .place(x=150, y=134)

Gvim = IntVar(value=0)
GvimC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Gvim',
                    variable=Gvim,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="cyan2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=150, y=153)

NotePad = IntVar(value=0)
NotePadC= Checkbutton(win,
                      text='NotePad',
                      variable=NotePad,
                      bg="gray6",
                      fg="cyan2",
                      activebackground="gray6",
                      activeforeground="green3",
                      selectcolor="gray6",
                      )\
                      .place(x=150, y=172)

SublimeText = IntVar(value=0)
SublimeTextC= Checkbutton(win,
                 text='SublimeText',
                 variable=SublimeText,
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="cyan2",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="green3",
                 selectcolor="gray6",
                 )\
                 .place(x=150, y=191)

Thonny = IntVar(value=0)
ThonnyC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='Thonny',
                  variable=Thonny,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=210)

VSCode = IntVar(value=0)
VSCodeC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='VSCode',
                  variable=VSCode,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="cyan2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=150, y=229)

Zip = IntVar(value=0)
ZipC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='7z',
                  variable=Zip,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=1)

CDbxp = IntVar(value=0)
CDbxpC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='CDbxp',
                  variable=CDbxp,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=20)

Everything = IntVar(value=0)
EverythingC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='Everything',
                  variable=Everything,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=39)

LockHunter = IntVar(value=0)
LockHunterC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='LockHunter',
                    variable=LockHunter,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="RoyalBlue3",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=290, y=58)

Unlocker = IntVar(value=0)
UnlockerC = Checkbutton(win,
                            text='Unlocker',
                            variable=Unlocker,
                            bg="gray6",
                            fg="RoyalBlue3",
                            activebackground="gray6",
                            activeforeground="green3",
                            selectcolor="gray6",
                            )\
                            .place(x=290, y=77)

Windirstat = IntVar(value=0)
WindirstatC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Windirstat',
                    variable=Windirstat,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="RoyalBlue3",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=290, y=96)

winRAR = IntVar(value=0)
winRARC= Checkbutton(win,
                      text='winRAR',
                      variable=winRAR,
                      bg="gray6",
                      fg="RoyalBlue3",
                      activebackground="gray6",
                      activeforeground="green3",
                      selectcolor="gray6",
                      )\
                      .place(x=290, y=115)

AIDA64 = IntVar(value=0)
AIDA64C= Checkbutton(win,
                 text='AIDA64',
                 variable=AIDA64,
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="RoyalBlue3",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="green3",
                 selectcolor="gray6",
                 )\
                 .place(x=290, y=134)

AnvirTM = IntVar(value=0)
AnvirTMC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='AnvirTM',
                  variable=AnvirTM,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=153)

CoreTemp = IntVar(value=0)
CoreTempC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='CoreTemp',
                  variable=CoreTemp,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=172)

CpuZ = IntVar(value=0)
CpuZC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='CpuZ',
                  variable=CpuZ,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=191)

GpuZ = IntVar(value=0)
GpuZC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='GpuZ',
                  variable=GpuZ,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=210)

HDTunePro = IntVar(value=0)
HDTuneProC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='HDTunePro',
                  variable=HDTunePro,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="RoyalBlue3",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=290, y=229)

InfoCD = IntVar(value=0)
InfoCDC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='InfoCD',
                    variable=InfoCD,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="IndianRed2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=430, y=1)

MarkCD = IntVar(value=0)
MarkCDC = Checkbutton(win,
                            text='MarkCD',
                            variable=MarkCD,
                            bg="gray6",
                            fg="IndianRed2",
                            activebackground="gray6",
                            activeforeground="green3",
                            selectcolor="gray6",
                            )\
                            .place(x=430, y=20)

MSIAfterburner = IntVar(value=0)
MSIAfterburnerC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='MSIAfterburner',
                    variable=MSIAfterburner,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="IndianRed2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=430, y=39)

AIMP = IntVar(value=0)
AIMPC= Checkbutton(win,
                      text='AIMP',
                      variable=AIMP,
                      bg="gray6",
                      fg="IndianRed2",
                      activebackground="gray6",
                      activeforeground="green3",
                      selectcolor="gray6",
                      )\
                      .place(x=430, y=58)

CyberLink = IntVar(value=0)
CyberLinkC= Checkbutton(win,
                 text='CyberLink',
                 variable=CyberLink,
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="IndianRed2",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="green3",
                 selectcolor="gray6",
                 )\
                 .place(x=430, y=77)

Gimp = IntVar(value=0)
GimpC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='Gimp',
                  variable=Gimp,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="IndianRed2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=430, y=96)

KMPlayer = IntVar(value=0)
KMPlayerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='KMPlayer',
                  variable=KMPlayer,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="IndianRed2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=430, y=115)

Lightshot = IntVar(value=0)
LightshotC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='Lightshot',
                  variable=Lightshot,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="IndianRed2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=430, y=134)

Picasa = IntVar(value=0)
PicasaC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Picasa',
                    variable=Picasa,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="IndianRed2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=430, y=153)

VLC = IntVar(value=0)
VLCC = Checkbutton(win,
                            text='VLC',
                            variable=VLC,
                            bg="gray6",
                            fg="IndianRed2",
                            activebackground="gray6",
                            activeforeground="green3",
                            selectcolor="gray6",
                            )\
                            .place(x=430, y=172)

Xrecode = IntVar(value=0)
XrecodeC = Checkbutton(win,
                    text='Xrecode',
                    variable=Xrecode,
                    bg="gray6",
                    fg="IndianRed2",
                    activebackground="gray6",
                    activeforeground="green3",
                    selectcolor="gray6",
                    )\
                    .place(x=430, y=191)

DriverBooster = IntVar(value=0)
DriverBoosterC= Checkbutton(win,
                      text='DriverBooster',
                      variable=DriverBooster,
                      bg="gray6",
                      fg="IndianRed2",
                      activebackground="gray6",
                      activeforeground="green3",
                      selectcolor="gray6",
                      )\
                      .place(x=430, y=210)

DriverHub = IntVar(value=0)
DriverHubC= Checkbutton(win,
                 text='DriverHub',
                 variable=DriverHub,
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="IndianRed2",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="green3",
                 selectcolor="gray6",
                 )\
                 .place(x=430, y=229)

EarTrumpet = IntVar(value=0)
EarTrumpetC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='EarTrumpet',
                  variable=EarTrumpet,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="honeydew2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=570, y=1)

MiniBin = IntVar(value=0)
MiniBinC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='MiniBin',
                  variable=MiniBin,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="honeydew2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=570, y=20)

TimeER = IntVar(value=0)
TimeERC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='TimeER',
                  variable=TimeER,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="honeydew2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=570, y=39)

VNCServer = IntVar(value=0)
VNCServerC = Checkbutton(win,
                  text='VNCServer',
                  variable=VNCServer,
                  bg="gray6",
                  fg="honeydew2",
                  activebackground="gray6",
                  activeforeground="green3",
                  selectcolor="gray6",
                  )\
                  .place(x=570, y=58)




ForNotebook = Button(win,
                 text='SP For Notebook',
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="khaki1",
                 bd="0",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="lawn green",
                 width="13",
                 height="1",
                 command=ForNotebook)
ForNotebook.place(x=10, y=253)
Hovertip(ForNotebook, 'Yandex\nuTorrent\nMicrosoftOffice\nDriverBooster\nUninstallTool'
'\nNotepad++\nPicasa\nMiniBin\nEarThumper\nEverything\nLightshot\nFlux'
'\nBattery\nTach_B590')


ForPC = Button(win,
                 text='SP For PC',
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="khaki1",
                 bd="0",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="lawn green",
                 width="8",
                 height="1",
                 command=ForPC)
ForPC.place(x=200, y=253)
Hovertip(ForPC, 'Yandex\nuTorrent\nMicrosoftOffice\nDriverBooster\nUninstallTool'
'\nNotepad++\nPicasa\nMiniBin\nEarThumper\nEverything\nLightshot\nFlux')



Install = Button(win,
                 text='Install',
                 bg="gray6",
                 fg="gold",
                 bd="0",
                 activebackground="gray6",
                 activeforeground="lawn green",
                 width="4",
                 height="1",
                 command=Install)
Install.place(x=390, y=253)
Hovertip(Install, 'Installation of marked programs')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ошибка не из-за subprocess, а вероятно из-за того, что у вас для отступов табы и пробелы вперемешку используются.

Comment: В sublime text исправляется через меню View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation to Spaces. Ну и если выделить текст, то будет видно где табы, где пробелы, вот например палка вместо точек (отдельных пробелов) - это таб: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIzhV.png